# installation of swirl in R for version 3.4.4

Tags: r

trying to install 'swirl' on R version 3.4.4.

Get the following answer:

```
Error in install.packages : cannot open file 'C:/Users/diego/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/file28904d8317d/assertthat/DESCRIPTION': Permission denied
packageVersion("swirl")
Error in packageVersion("swirl") : package ‘swirl’ not found
> library(swirl)
Error in library(swirl) : there is no package called ‘swirl’
```

Comment: This kind of thing sometimes happens if you have a virus checker active:  R does a temp install, the virus checker locks the files, R can't finish the install.

Comment: Have you checked if that file exists on your system and do you have reading permissions for it?